# Does the word appendix have to be always capitalised

Tags: capitalization

When I refer to a section in-text, I use small letters like:

> ..(see section 1 for more details).

I am proofreading a document using grammarily. I have appendix not section.

> ..(see appendix A for more details).

It is suggesting to capetalise it, but it does not suggest this for sections. Can any one confirm to me if `appendix` must be capitalised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different styles that are possible, so you don't have to capitalise.  However many style guides do recommend using title case, and referring to "Appendix A".

If you are following a particular style guide, you should check it. If not, I'd recommend putting it in capitals, even if it is not absolutely required.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using lower-case letters in "section 1", it is appropriate for you to also use lower-case letters in "appendix A".

The word "section" has more uses and meanings than "appendix".  It might have been easier for your grammar checker's programmers to figure out whether the word "appendix" is part of the title of an appendix, than to figure out if the word "section" is part of the title of a section.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion to be consistent. That said, I'd probably use upper-case for both, rather than lower-case for both.